# Pinging router at 192.168.1.1 returns response from 192.168.0.34

Tags: networking, ping, ipconfig

In simple home network, how it is possible to `ping 192.168.1.1` and get a response from **192.168.0.34**? Mikrotik router RB951G-2HnD (mipsbe) firmware v. 3.18.

- The router sits at gateway IP address **192.168.1.1**
- Subnet mask is **255.255.255.0**

[image]

Accompanying symptoms:

- All devices are only on **192.168.1.X** so **192.168.0.X** is not used.
- All known devices except of my PC have static IP addresses assigned manually, no other dynamically assigned ones (DHCP) are currently present in the network.
- Internet connection at the PC looks to be interrupted – for no obvious reason (i.e. after no obvious action from my side; + there seems to be no real outage from the provider).
- ipconfig shows that IP configuration is lost (there are no devices left which keep any IP config).
- `ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew` hangs at `ipconfig /renew` and times out.
- IMPORTANT: Internet connection will be restored only if I disconnect and reconnect wireless connection. (Then it will be restored immediately and `ping 192.168.1.1` again returns response from **192.168.1.1** as expected.)
- On my PC I'm using ESET Security suite (firewall, antivirus, etc. ... maybe not related)
- There's nothing poisonous in `.hosts` file.
- I think there are no other DHCP devices on the network. Currently I'm the only PC on the network, there is one managed switch (mgmt page seems to be unreachable, strange) and one IP phone connected to the switch (reachable).
- After I recovered the connection (as mentioned above)

  - pinging **192.168.0.34** writes `General Failure`:
    [image]
  - `tracert` for the above addresses:
    [image]
- █ If I disconnect from the network, then unlike **192.168.1.1**, IP **192.168.0.34** is still present and throwing the above general failures.

**It looks there is a problem with the PC rather than with the network, but how can I find what is that strange `192.168.0.34` which persists after disconnecting and occassionally also shadows the gateway?**

---

`ipconfig /all`: (with some names redacted as ********)

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : idea-PC-****
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

PPP adapter ********:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : ********
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.160.103(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.160.1
                                       85.159.106.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 20-68-9D-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter OpenVPN:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-CB-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Team Viewer VPN:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TeamViewer VPN Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-D3-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ********.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 20-68-9D-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8723A Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 20-68-9D-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::298a:5d0a:6108:9e10%3(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.198(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 10. august 2016 16:49:01
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 10. august 2016 18:05:23
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 337668253
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-2C-5C-DA-20-68-9D-**-**-**
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{577E0F04-78FE-45D4-8CC7-370D517FAD06}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 14:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:cfe:3d8e:a72b:db42(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cfe:3d8e:a72b:db42%18(Preferred) 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301989888
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-2C-5C-DA-20-68-9D-**-**-**
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{79A29C84-EF40-4CAA-B186-B9B323C39B2C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.********.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ********.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: I take it when the static IP is set that the gateway is set to `192.168.1.1`? And also check the `hosts` file.

Comment: @BittenFleax – I have changed and updated the facts. Please [see diffs](http://superuser.com/posts/1112063/revisions)

Comment: When it's doing this, can you ping 192.168.0.34?  Are you sure there's no other devices acting as a DHCP server on your network (another router, WAP, WiFi repeater, etc.)?

Comment: Try a tracert, it will show the route taken for the ping. Also, what is your subnet mask? What happens if you use a browser to open 192.168.0.34?

Comment: We need a ping and tracert to 192.168.0.34 when the problem you're describing is happening, not when 192.168.1.1 is answering as expected. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 – I think I can update the answer later when the problem is back, but OTOH, 192.168.0.34 is acting strangely right now, and it is "present" even **after I completely disconnected from the network**. Is there a way to learn who is sitting there?

Comment: Can you give an `ipconfig /all` output?

Comment: @miroxlav I created this chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/43754/pinging-router-at-192-168-1-1-returns-response-from-192-168-0-34?tab=general, to avoid having too many comments here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your adapters might be interfering w/ your connection.

Try disabling VPN clients' adapters and then re-enabling them.

Comment: True. I disabled all adapters except the Wi-FI and re-enabled them. The strange IP 192.168.0.34 disappeared. I did not verify which one was causing that, perhaps I'll be able to find out next time when this happens. Thank you.